# Evaluate $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The first substitution that came to my mind was
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \tan(\theta) \\
dx = \sec^2\theta d\theta \\
\textrm{Bounds:} \, \, 0 \to \, \pi/2
\end{cases}
$$
We now have:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(\tan(\theta))\cos^4\theta \, d \theta
$$
But that really doesn't seem to help. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A closed form involves [Struve functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5#E7).

Comment: Mathematica gives no nicer closed form than one involving Bessel and Struve functions.

Comment: @PatrickStevens [Nor does Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28sin+x%29%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29+from+0+to+inf).

Answer (score 2):

Changing the integration variable to $t$ for ease of comparison with Eq. 11.5.7 in @metamorphy's [DLMF link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5#E7), $\nu=0,\,x=1$ gives$$\int_0^\infty(1+t^2)^{-1/2}\sin t\mathrm dt=\frac{\pi}{2}(I_0(1)-L_0(1)),$$with $I_0$ a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) and $L_0$ a [modified Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).